# MVC ASP.NET How to show View Model Data by Grouping in HTML Listing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing MVC Asp.Net web page on a requirement to show grouping of data in HTML Listing for the data below:

1. Sentence A

   a. Item A

   ```
   i. Sub Item 1
   ii. Sub Item 2
   ```
2. Sentence A

   a. Item B

   ```
   i. Sub Item 3
   ```

I need to show the final result as below:

1. Sentence A

   a. Item A

   ```
   i. Sub Item 1
   ii. Sub Item 2
   ```

   b. Item B

   ```
   i. Sub Item 3
   ```

Anyone did the similar thing before? I have no idea how to display the data in such manner.

Comment: Can you show us how are you retrieving data from the data source and how are displaying that in the view?

Comment: I have a List<ViewModel> which data retrieved from database. 
Then I do a  foreach (var item in ViewModelList) to display the data in  HTML as below:

<li>@Html.Raw(item.DocumentMainContent)</li> 

for item.DocumentContentItem, I display in 
<ol type="a">                                                        <li>@Html.Raw(item.DocumentContentItem) </li>
 </ol>

Comment: What is the structure of viewModel? Can you share the view code too?

Comment: I have a List<ViewModel> which data retrieved from database. 
Then I do a  foreach (var item in ViewModelList) to display the data in  HTML as below:

<li>@Html.Raw(item.DocumentMainContent)</li> 

for item.DocumentContentItem, I display in 
<ol type="a">                                                        <li>@Html.Raw(item.DocumentContentItem) </li>
 </ol>

For SubItem, I display in  

<ol type="i">
@foreach ( var subItemList in ViewModelSubList )
  {                                                             <li>@Html.Raw(firmBranchList.FirmBranchName)</li>
}
 </ol>

Comment: @SteveFu all of the code info you are providing should be edits to the question where is is more readable. Do not put code clarification in the comments. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44735318/edit) for this question to add any code snippets that can be used as a [mcve] that better explains the problem

Comment: Code posted in comment is not readable at all. Please update your question and put the code there. Also as I asked previously share the code of ViewModel class too.